# Dynamic appended iframe with dynamic content write jquery event handle on content elements not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

I have appended dynamic iframe on document ready through jquery.
`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


 $("body").append(renderIframe());
  });}
```

`
Well iframe rendered through this function

```
function renderIframe(){


 return [

  '<div id="mydiv">',
     '<iframe id="frame" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;display:none"  height="120%" width="120%">',
     '</iframe>',
 '</div>'
  ].join("")

  }
```

On Ajax call writing iframe content
`

```
 var iFrame = $('#frame');
      iFrame.contents().attr('target','_parent');

   var htmlDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(data, "text/html");

      var iFrameDoc = iFrame[0].contentDocument || iFrame[0].contentWindow.document;
   iFrameDoc.write( htmlDoc.documentElement.outerHTML);
   iFrameDoc.close();`
```

And trying to handle event like

```
 $('document').on('load','#frame', function(){
    console.log("frame loaded")
    $(this).contents().find('body').on('click', '#btnClose', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(e);
        alert("link clicked!" );
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several issues here.

- `iFrame.contents().attr('target','_parent');` will add the `target` attribute to every element in the DOM. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that but it's not a good idea.
- The iframe is empty at that point anyway, so nothing will happen and the line can be removed.
- the `renderIframe()` logic doesn't really need it's own function; it only ever returns a single string, and contains no business logic.
- You don't need to create a `DOMParser` instance to generate a DOM structure from your HTML string. Just set the `innerHTML` within the iframe directly using the string you receive from the AJAX request
- iframes don't fire a `load` event, so that code block will never fire. A better idea is to just attach the event handler within the AJAX callback after the content is populated.
- If you're expecting the content to be visible in the page you need to remove the `display: none` setting in the CSS.
- On the topic of CSS, do not put it the inline `style` attribute of the HTML element. Use a external stylesheet.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$("body").append(renderIframe());

function renderIframe() {
  return '<div id="mydiv"><iframe id="frame"></iframe></div>';
}

// inside the AJAX callback:
var iFrame = $('#frame');
let data = '<p>Lorem ipsum</p><button id="btnClose">Close</button>'; // AJAX response
var iFrameDoc = iFrame[0].contentDocument || iFrame[0].contentWindow.document;
iFrameDoc.body.innerHTML = data;

$('#frame').contents().find('body').on('click', '#btnClose', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(e);
  alert("link clicked!");
});
```

Note that SO Snippets disallow iframes, so here's a jsFiddle containing a [**working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/e2urp4w9/).

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer, Actually on AJAX POST  am receiving Bootstrap Modal with server side rendering in form of  HTML page . Well I have replaced the DOMParser  with iframe innerhtml , the Modal is not opening now.

Comment: Well in that case why are you putting a Bootstrap modal in to an iframe? That makes no sense

Comment: Just to make it overlay on whole screen. other wise it doesn't make sense your right.

Comment: BTW why Modal is not working in this case, can you please elaborate?

Comment: I can't really say why it doesn't work for you without seeing the relevant code. However if the HTML is a bootstrap modal you really should show it as such, not hacking it around to display in an iframe. You're just creating more problems by doing that

Comment: Btw Thanks for the answer, I have attach the event handler within the AJAX callback and its worked.

Comment: Actually am working on shopify app where I have to deal with shopify store front end . Well I have tried to append Modal directly in page  but its breaking site style so I have decided to use iframe.